# OpenPyxl Getting the real cell value when cell's text contains a slash

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Python 3.7 OpenPyxl
In my Excel file, the cell value is 'HP 934XL/935XL'
My code reads the value with a simple instruction :
cle = sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value

When debugging or printing the value is

```
'HP 934XL\/935XL'
```

is it a standard behavior from this OpenPyxl ?

Comment: The escaping is not coming from openpyxl.

Answer (score 0):

The `/` has been escaped so it becomes `\/`.

Use:
`cle = sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value.decode('string_escape')`
or
`.decode('unicode_escape')`
depending on Python version.

Example:

```
>>> print '"Hello,\\nworld!"'.decode('string_escape')
Hello,
world!
```

You can also use:

```
>>> import ast
>>> escaped_str = '"Hello,\\nworld!"'
>>> print ast.literal_eval(escaped_str)
Hello,
world!
```

Comment: "/" is generally not escaped in Python.